# ValueError: Expected n_neighbors <= n_samples (mismatch between the number of neighbors specified and the number of samples in the data)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to implement multi-view spectral clustering.

The `supervised_multi_view_spectral_clustering` function takes multiple views of feature matrices (`X_views`), a target variable (`y`), and clustering parameters, and performs spectral clustering on the concatenated features.

The second function finds the optimal number of clusters based on silhouette scores when given a list of mixed representations.

The final part of the code uses these functions to determine the optimal number of clusters and performs multi-view spectral clustering on the provided data (`mixed_representation_all`).

By design, the input `latent_representations_train_nmf` is a dictionary of numpy array, whereas y is a multi-variate dataframe.

The error indicates that there is a mismatch between the number of neighbors specified and the number of samples in the data. This is despite ensuring that n_neighbors is always less than or equal to the number of samples.

Code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.cluster import SpectralClustering
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

def supervised_multi_view_spectral_clustering(X_views, y, n_clusters, affinity='nearest_neighbors', max_neighbors=10):

    # Check if y is already encoded
    if isinstance(y.iloc[0, 0], str):  # Assuming the first element of the dataframe is a string if not encoded
        # Encode labels if they are not numerical
        label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
        y_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(y)
    else:
        # Use the provided encoded y directly
        y_encoded = y

    # Concatenate feature matrices along axis 1
    X_concatenated = np.hstack(X_views)

    # Calculate the maximum allowed number of neighbors
    max_allowed_neighbors = min(X_concatenated.shape[0] - 1, max_neighbors)

    # Create affinity matrix using concatenated features
    if affinity == 'nearest_neighbors':
        from sklearn.neighbors import kneighbors_graph
        adjacency_matrix = kneighbors_graph(X_concatenated, n_neighbors=max_allowed_neighbors, mode='connectivity', include_self=True)
    elif affinity == 'rbf':
        from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import rbf_kernel
        adjacency_matrix = rbf_kernel(X_concatenated, gamma=0.5)

    # Convert the adjacency matrix to a Laplacian matrix
    laplacian_matrix = np.diag(np.sum(adjacency_matrix, axis=1)) - adjacency_matrix

    # Compute the generalized eigenvalues and eigenvectors
    _, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eigh(laplacian_matrix)

    # Use eigenvectors corresponding to the smallest eigenvalues as features for clustering
    X_cluster = eigenvectors[:, :n_clusters]

    # Apply spectral clustering on the selected features
    spectral = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=n_clusters, affinity='nearest_neighbors', random_state=42, n_neighbors=max_allowed_neighbors)
    labels = spectral.fit_predict(X_cluster)

    # Evaluate clustering performance using the ground truth labels (y_encoded)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_encoded, labels)
    print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy:.2f}")

    return labels

def find_optimal_clusters_multi_view(mixed_representation_list, max_clusters=10):
    silhouette_scores = []

    for n_clusters in range(2, max_clusters + 1):
        all_labels = []
        for X_cluster in mixed_representation_list:
            # Apply spectral clustering on the selected features
            spectral = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=n_clusters, affinity='nearest_neighbors', random_state=42)
            labels = spectral.fit_predict(X_cluster)
            all_labels.append(labels)

        # Calculate silhouette score using all labels
        silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(np.hstack(all_labels), np.arange(len(np.hstack(all_labels))))
        silhouette_scores.append(silhouette_avg)

    # Find the optimal number of clusters based on the highest silhouette score
    optimal_clusters = np.argmax(silhouette_scores) + 2  # Add 2 to start from n_clusters=2

    return optimal_clusters

# Concatenate latent representations for all datasets
mixed_representation_all = []

for key, (data, _) in train_data_dict.items():
    mixed_representation_all.append(
        np.concatenate([
            latent_representations_train_nmf[key],
            encoder_models[key].predict(data),
            train_data_dict[key][1]
        ], axis=1)
    )

n_clusters = find_optimal_clusters_multi_view(mixed_representation_all)
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [189], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 n_clusters = find_optimal_clusters_multi_view(mixed_representation_all)
      3 # Multi-View Spectral Clustering       
      4 labels = supervised_multi_view_spectral_clustering(
      5     X_views=mixed_representation_all,
      6     y=y,  # Use the multi-variate dataframe directly
   (...)
      9     n_neighbors=max(1, min(int(total_samples * 0.1), total_samples))  # Use 10% of the samples as neighbors, with a minimum of 1
     10 )

Input In [185], in find_optimal_clusters_multi_view(mixed_representation_list, max_clusters)
      6 for X_cluster in mixed_representation_list:
      7     # Apply spectral clustering on the selected features
      8     spectral = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=n_clusters, affinity='nearest_neighbors', random_state=42)
----> 9     labels = spectral.fit_predict(X_cluster)
     10     all_labels.append(labels)
     12 # Calculate silhouette score using all labels

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/_spectral.py:657, in SpectralClustering.fit_predict(self, X, y)
    635 def fit_predict(self, X, y=None):
    636     """Perform spectral clustering on `X` and return cluster labels.
    637 
    638     Parameters
   (...)
    655         Cluster labels.
    656     """
--> 657     return super().fit_predict(X, y)

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:736, in ClusterMixin.fit_predict(self, X, y)
    718 """
    719 Perform clustering on `X` and returns cluster labels.
    720 
   (...)
    732     Cluster labels.
    733 """
    734 # non-optimized default implementation; override when a better
    735 # method is possible for a given clustering algorithm
--> 736 self.fit(X)
    737 return self.labels_

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/_spectral.py:597, in SpectralClustering.fit(self, X, y)
    589     warnings.warn(
    590         "The spectral clustering API has changed. ``fit``"
    591         "now constructs an affinity matrix from data. To use"
    592         " a custom affinity matrix, "
    593         "set ``affinity=precomputed``."
    594     )
    596 if self.affinity == "nearest_neighbors":
--> 597     connectivity = kneighbors_graph(
    598         X, n_neighbors=self.n_neighbors, include_self=True, n_jobs=self.n_jobs
    599     )
    600     self.affinity_matrix_ = 0.5 * (connectivity + connectivity.T)
    601 elif self.affinity == "precomputed_nearest_neighbors":

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/_graph.py:125, in kneighbors_graph(X, n_neighbors, mode, metric, p, metric_params, include_self, n_jobs)
    122     _check_params(X, metric, p, metric_params)
    124 query = _query_include_self(X._fit_X, include_self, mode)
--> 125 return X.kneighbors_graph(X=query, n_neighbors=n_neighbors, mode=mode)

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/_base.py:881, in KNeighborsMixin.kneighbors_graph(self, X, n_neighbors, mode)
    877 # check the input only in self.kneighbors
    878 
    879 # construct CSR matrix representation of the k-NN graph
    880 if mode == "connectivity":
--> 881     A_ind = self.kneighbors(X, n_neighbors, return_distance=False)
    882     n_queries = A_ind.shape[0]
    883     A_data = np.ones(n_queries * n_neighbors)

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/_base.py:727, in KNeighborsMixin.kneighbors(self, X, n_neighbors, return_distance)
    725 n_samples_fit = self.n_samples_fit_
    726 if n_neighbors > n_samples_fit:
--> 727     raise ValueError(
    728         "Expected n_neighbors <= n_samples, "
    729         " but n_samples = %d, n_neighbors = %d" % (n_samples_fit, n_neighbors)
    730     )
    732 n_jobs = effective_n_jobs(self.n_jobs)
    733 chunked_results = None

ValueError: Expected n_neighbors <= n_samples,  but n_samples = 5, n_neighbors = 10
```

Input:

`latent_representations_train_nmf`

```
{'transcriptomics': array([[0.89114348, 0.        , 0.57196997],
        [0.00345458, 0.18141511, 1.64166316],
        [1.17455724, 0.        , 0.07521701],
        [0.1824264 , 1.08355303, 0.        ],
        [0.        , 1.69336632, 0.16080944]]),
 'epigenomics': array([[0.99835429, 0.33314585, 0.08142486],
        [0.9975858 , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 1.52494875, 0.        ],
        [0.78755341, 0.96162343, 0.02395076],
        [0.        , 0.        , 1.90771206]]),
 'proteomics': array([[0.17911176, 0.        , 1.09040506],
        [0.        , 0.33613625, 0.46545103],
        [0.        , 1.15705006, 0.        ],
        [0.99305495, 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.73511861, 0.53718761, 0.210258  ]])}
```

`y`

```
pd.DataFrame({'Overall_Survival': {'sample_1': 0,
  'sample_2': 0,
  'sample_3': 1,
  'sample_4': 0,
  'sample_5': 0,
  'sample_6': 1,
  'sample_7': 0,
  'sample_8': 1},
 'Immune_Response': {'sample_1': 1,
  'sample_2': 1,
  'sample_3': 1,
  'sample_4': 1,
  'sample_5': 0,
  'sample_6': 0,
  'sample_7': 1,
  'sample_8': 0}})
```

Comment: *"This is despite ensuring that n_neighbors is always less than or equal to the number of samples."* - are you sure that you have done this in `find_optimal_clusters_multi_view`? In that function, you don't specify `n_neighbors` when instantiating `SpectralClustering`, so it defaults to 10: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering